# Buffer.isBuffer() is not a function in zlib

Tags: javascript, reactjs, buffer, gzip, zlib

I was using the zlib library for gzipping my streams in React js using **zlib.gzip()** method. This was working perfectly fine a couple of months back. But recently I am getting an error saying ***Buffer.isBuffer() is not a function*** when I am trying to use the zlib.gzip() method.
I noticed the same error for the gunzip, inflate and deflate methods too.

I am using nodejs version 14 and the zlib version 1.0.5.

Any kind of help is appreciated on this one.

Thanks !

edit:

adding the error stack,

*TypeError: Buffer.isBuffer is not a function
at _isUint8Array (http://localhost:5000/main.bundle.js:488941:17)
at Gzip../node_modules/stream-browserify/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js.Writable.write (http://localhost:5000/main.bundle.js:489169:36)
at Gzip../node_modules/stream-browserify/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js.Writable.end (http://localhost:5000/main.bundle.js:489437:51)
at zlibBuffer (http://localhost:5000/main.bundle.js:298272:10)
at Object../node_modules/browserify-zlib/lib/index.js.exports.gzip (http://localhost:5000/main.bundle.js:298198:10)
at Object.onClick (http://localhost:5000/main.bundle.js:68477:14)
at Button.onClick (http://localhost:5000/main.bundle.js:464007:25)
at Button.onClick (http://localhost:5000/main.bundle.js:437509:25)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:5000/main.bundle.js:412829:14)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:5000/main.bundle.js:412878:16)*

Comment: Can you show us the error stack?

Comment: Hi @Geshode, I have edited the question to add the error stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error stack gives me the impression that you are running Zlib on the client-side (browser). Buffer API is only available on the server-side.

Comment: Yeah that was the issue. Thanks for the input. Using pako for the same now instead of zlib.